# What exactly was the "classical model" of black-body radiation, and what assumption about it made it wrong?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation, frequency

While studying [black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation), I saw that most of the textbooks and videos I watched mentioned that there was a contradiction between the classical  model of black body radiation and experimental data, which created the ultraviolet catastrophe. They all said that the classical model predicted continous increase in spectral radiance as wavelength decreased.

However, none of them describe how the classical model worked, and what assumption about it made it wrong. Could someone explain what this was?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let me add something to anna v's answer.
The classical model of blackbody radiation is based on:

1. an exact recasting of the Maxwell equations describing electromagnetic radiation in a cavity, which shows that this physical system can be described as an infinite set of classical harmonic oscillators (normal modes) whose frequencies start from zero and are not upper bounded;
2. the hypothesis that there is an effective mechanism which allows thermal equilibrium of the radiation field;
3. that statistical mechanics can be applied to such a system to calculate equilibrium properties.

All together, these hypotheses have as a consequence that:

1. due to the equipartition theorem, each normal mode should contribute to the internal energy with the same average energy: ( $k_BT$ );
2. in a given volume and interval of frequencies  $d\nu$, the number of normal modes grows like $\nu^2$;
3. therefore the total energy per unit volume diverges, due to the unintegrable growth of normal modes at high frequencies (from here, the name *ultraviolet catastrophe*).

Up to here, these are the facts textbooks refer to. However, there are a few facts that could be useful to know to put things in the historical perspective and, more important, to learn a lesson which could be useful in other contexts even today.

The actual weight of the *ultraviolet catastrophe* argument on the historical development of quantum physics is usually over-exagerated. It looks compelling for us, but for contemporaries of Rayleigh and Jeans, it was not a clear indication that something was wrong with classical mechanics. Statistical mechanics was in its infancy and not everybody was convinced of its general validity. Remember that Boltzmann had a hard time convincing the scientific community of the truth of his ideas. In particular, the general validity of equipartition theorem was not acknowledged by everybody.

Somewhat connected with this observation, reading the first paper where Planck derived his distribution makes clear that he was not concerned by any *ultraviolet catastrophe* (which is not mentioned in any place in his two main contributions to the blackbody radiation). On the contrary, his main concern was the disagreement between new experiments by Pringsheim and Lummer and Wien's energy distribution **at low frequencies** (long wavelengths). A readable account of the real history of Planck's contribution to the blackbody problem can be found in the paper [Klein, M. J. (1962). Max Planck and the beginnings of the quantum theory. Archive for History of Exact Sciences, 1(5), 459-479](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/41133222.pdf?casa_token=VM4OFs35hiQAAAAA:zPyjGu8Ou-yvEyrlKOEBxZg8ugnmpBjFhBDXvP-U1cYfamf_c2quF7URal9c8ji96mOFlR7g-t1tL7etqwep_EhDpjHjR1p_OMr68bG0pnidQZ3tPw).

A final comment on hypothesis n.2 (see above). 20-th century research on dynamical systems has shown that when oscillators with very different frequencies are weakly coupled, equilibration times could easily exceed any reasonable experimental time. In a way, it was a lucky circumstance for the birth of Quantum Mechanics that such a result was not clearly known at the beginning of the century.

Comment: What are these number of modes?

Comment: @Buraian the number of independent harmonic oscillator-like  solutions of the e.m. equations which describe the electromagnetic field.

Comment: A lucky circumstance? Maybe it was unlucky, not lucky. The absence of ultra-high frequency modes in the black body cavity is easily seen from the fact that ordinary quantum mechanics, i.e. the Schroedinger equation, shows that these modes are suppressed on the mechanical side. So how could they occur in the cavity? In other words, you don't need photons to explain the black body equilibrium. This "lucky circumstance" has saddled future generations with the nonsensical photon, and all its philosophical contradictions which we have never gotten around.

Answer (score 13):

[This link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html)  clearly shows the classical and quantum derivations

> Blackbody radiation" or "cavity radiation" refers to an object or system which absorbs all radiation incident upon it and re-radiates energy which is characteristic of this radiating system only, not dependent upon the type of radiation which is incident upon it. The radiated energy can be considered to be produced by standing wave or resonant modes of the cavity which is radiating.

[image: bb]

> The amount of radiation emitted in a given frequency range should be proportional to the number of modes in that range. The best of classical physics suggested that all modes had an equal chance of being produced, and that the number of modes went up proportional to the square of the frequency.

> But the predicted continual increase in radiated energy with frequency (dubbed the "ultraviolet catastrophe") did not happen. Nature knew better.

[image: bb2]

The crucial point is that by demanding quantized modes with energy $hν$ the high frequencies become less probable.

Comment: Hi anna v, your comment has helped greatly - but just 1 follow up question:
I don't quite understand how the concept of quanta and the photon plays into probability. 
I can see that the parabolic increase in number of modes per unit frequency would cause the classical model. 

However, I'm not really sure how introducing the quanta changes the probability of the modes. Does it mean that the energy of a mode has to be exactly [hv] to be possible? But if then, wouldn't the probability of being equal to hv increase with frequency, because modes increase?

Thanks.

Comment: The quantization imposes higher energy modes  for higher frequencies,  For the same total energy, there will be a smaller number of modes, as the expression on the bottom left gives mathematically. the "less probable" describe that  in the total number of modes there are less high  energy modes. It is a model that proved successful.

Comment: @KyogoSakai the classical model let you "construct" a high-frequency, low-energy "photon", but QM says: "the frequency determines the energy; if you wanna make a high-frequency photon, you need to have a *lot* of energy".

Comment: @LawnmowerMan Wow I could have saved quite some hours during my studies if my textbook had said it as clearly as you just did.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

The classical version of blackbody radiation is given by the Rayleigh-Jeans law, and is described in detail in the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law).

Answer (score 2):

I'll rephrase comment by @LawnmowerMan as a new answer:

The assumption that "classical model" had wrong was that it assumed frequency and energy of a photon are not connected. For example, it allowed photons that are both high-frequency and low-energy.

However, quantum mechanism and real world experiments show that the energy and frequency of a photon are strongly interconnected and as such there cannot be such photons.

Answer (score 1):

There is unstability or not reaching thermal equilibirium according to classical model as average energy is constant $kT$, if consider system is at thermal equilibirium. As number of modes increases, exponentially and no limit on how much modes participate. Because modes are frequency based and there is no restriction for how small dimension becomes. But these frequency comes from number of particles and they are finite because cavity is closed, otherwise it never become stable.

This is false that classical model fails because it is unstable. When temperature is finite, how one expect energy of system is infinite or inifinite modes available. The average energy of quantum model also had constant energy, the frequency term in it is not variable and constant. If one integrate it with then exponential function not limit the participation of higher frequency and integrating it with constant gives very low value and as unstable as classical.

We know that even considering frequency as variable, the average energy of cavity approaches classical model's average energy at higher temperature. The advantage of using any method is that as energy is limited by temperature, so number of modes also but, as particles goes to higher energy returns to lower state and body continuously emit radiation.

As energy increases by increase in temperature, but energy of quantum oscillator remain same because,$$Nhf_0=\varepsilon$$where $f_0$ is fundamental frequency and constant, $h$ is constant by Planck and $N$ is constant because either material of cavity or dimension of cavity is fixed. So total energy is constant for higher temperature, thus at higher temperature average energy is $kT$.